# In the new Stack Exchange window, if you switch to a section while another is loading, you get content from both

Tags: bug, status-completed, ajax, stack-exchange-button

The dropdown defaulted to "hot questions," but took a while to load, so I clicked on "all sites" instead while I was waiting. When the Ajax requests both finished, I got a list containing both types of items:

[image]

Comment: +1 for using Windows Classic theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got it ironed out - this will be deployed in a few minutes!